# boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload object to S3 bucket: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, minio, identity-management

I am trying to upload an object to an S3 bucket using boto3 and a **service account created by a user** with readwrite permissions. The IAM policy for the user is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload /tmp/tmpfnkhwptw/model/requirements.txt to ml-artifacts/1/02e5b8a81a834b6e83a3412745f4ff6a/artifacts/sklearn-model/requirements.txt: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied.
```

I've verified that the user is trying to upload the object to the correct bucket and prefix, and that the user has the correct permissions to write in the bucket -- this comes from a MLFlow example for a simple model using a wine dataset (can provide the code if wanted, but there's nothing special about it).

I am using MinIO as the object storage and the endpoint URL. The code works correctly if I use admin credentials, but not with user service account credentials.

What could be causing this error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: is there a bucket policy on the bucket?

Comment: I didn't configure any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I didn't give the whole information on my question. I thought service accounts were always necessary (I'm inexperienced) and didn't say that I was using the service account credentials.

The answer is as simple as using the user credentials and not the service account (created by said user) credentials.

Another thing I have learned is that the service account didn't work because, for some reason, my MinIO version didn't give the same privileges as the user who created it to the account. When I opted for giving specific access privileges to the service account and pasted the "readwrite" JSON config into it, it worked.